# How to correct an error of a struct in a switch

Tags: c

I am trying to use a structure with a switch, but it tells me that 'Contactos' is not declared. ¿Where is the problem here?

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Contacto {
char nombreContacto[30];
int Tf;
};

int main(){
FILE *AGENDA;
AGENDA = fopen("AGENDA.txt", "a"); 

/*Code with options*/

switch(opcion)
{
case 2:

struct Contacto Contactos;
   printf("ingresa el nombre del contacto:\n");
   fgets(Contactos.nombreContacto,30,stdin);
   printf("Cuantos numeros de telefono tiene el contacto:  \n");
   scanf("%d",&i);
   i--;
   while (i>=0){
   printf("ingresa el telefono %i del contacto:\n",i);
   scanf("%d",&Contactos.Tf);
   printf("\n");
  i--;}
     if(AGENDA){
fwrite(&Contactos,sizeof(struct Contacto),1,AGENDA);
fclose(AGENDA);
break;}}
```

There are the problems in the switch:
expected expresion (from the structure)
and undeclared identifier 'Contactos'

Comment: Is this your actual code? There are much more issues than just "undeclared identifier Contactos" ...

Comment: opcion and i is also undeclared

Comment: Please provide a [mrc] which in this case means that I should be able to copy your code, and when I try to compile the exact code I get the error message you specify. From this code I get a lot of errors.

Comment: I meant [mre]. I wrote mrc instead of mre. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Properly formatted code is essential for understanding your own code.

Answer (score 4):

Labeled statements cannot be declarations.

`case 2:` is a label. A label can be applied only to a *statement* in the C grammar. A *declaration* in the C grammar is not a *statement*. One way to remedy this is to put a null statement, such as `;` after the label:

```
case 2:
    ;
    struct Contacto Contactos;
```

Another way is to enclose the code of the case in a compound statement:

```
case 2:
{
    struct Contacto Contactos;
    …
}
```

The latter also has the benefit of limiting the scope of the declaration, which prevents the code for other cases from inadvertently using objects from this case.

In the C grammar, a *statement* is one of:

- A *compound-statement*, `{` … `}`.
- An *expression-statement*, such as an assignment statement, a function call, and other uses of expressions.
- A *selection-statement*, `if` or `switch`.
- An *iteration-statement*, `while`, `do`, or `for`.
- A *jump-statement*, `goto`, `continue`, `break`, or `return`.

A *declaration* is not a *statement* at all and can appear only at file scope, inside a *compound-statement*, or in certain parts of function declarations.